could not find `instruction` in `self` when putting code in a separate file
I am trying to work with Jupiter aggregation.
For the ease of readers I will only give the relevant codes:
Primarily, here is the lib.rs:
use crate::instructions::*;

pub mod instructions;

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::sysvar;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::sysvar::instructions::{
    load_current_index_checked, load_instruction_at_checked,
};
use anchor_lang::Discriminator;
use anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount;

use anchor_lang::system_program;

pub const AUTHORITY_SEED: &[u8] = b"authority";


#[program]
pub mod jupiter_borrow {
    use super::*;

pub fn borrow(ctx: Context<Borrow>) -> Result<()> {
        let ixs = ctx.accounts.instructions.to_account_info();

        let current_index = load_current_index_checked(&ixs)? as usize;
        let current_ix = load_instruction_at_checked(current_index, &ixs)?;
        if current_ix.program_id != *ctx.program_id {
            return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
        }

        let mut index = current_index + 1; // jupiter swap
        
        if let Ok(ix) = load_instruction_at_checked(index, &ixs) {
            if ix.program_id == crate::id() {
                let ix_discriminator: [u8; 8] = ix.data[0..8]
                    .try_into()
                    .map_err(|_| FlashFillError::SomeMismatch)?;

                if ix_discriminator == self::instruction::Borrow::discriminator() {
                    return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
                } else {
                    return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no more instructions, so we're missing a repay
            return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
        }

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Borrow<'info> {
    pub borrower: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [AUTHORITY_SEED], bump)]
    pub program_authority: SystemAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: check instructions account
    #[account(address = sysvar::instructions::ID @FlashFillError::SomeMismatch)]
    pub instructions: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

/// Errors for this program
#[error_code]
pub enum FlashFillError {
    #[msg("error")]
    SomeMismatch,
}

If I keep the code as it is and run anchor build, the code works fine.
But if I put the revevant codes in a separate file instructions.rs (separate file to keep the lib file clean) like this:
new lib.rs:
use crate::instructions::*;

pub mod instructions;

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[program]
pub mod jupiter_borrow {
    use super::*;

    pub fn borrow(ctx: Context<Borrow>) -> Result<()> {
    instructions::borrow(ctx)
    }
}

and instructions.rs:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::sysvar;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::sysvar::instructions::{
    load_current_index_checked, load_instruction_at_checked,
};
use anchor_lang::Discriminator;
use anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount;

use anchor_lang::system_program;

pub const AUTHORITY_SEED: &[u8] = b"authority";

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Borrow<'info> {
    pub borrower: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [AUTHORITY_SEED], bump)]
    pub program_authority: SystemAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: check instructions account
    #[account(address = sysvar::instructions::ID @FlashFillError::SomeMismatch)]
    pub instructions: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

/// Errors for this program
#[error_code]
pub enum FlashFillError {
    #[msg("error")]
    SomeMismatch,
}

pub fn borrow(ctx: Context<Borrow>) -> Result<()> {
    let ixs = ctx.accounts.instructions.to_account_info();

    let current_index = load_current_index_checked(&ixs)? as usize;
    let current_ix = load_instruction_at_checked(current_index, &ixs)?;
    if current_ix.program_id != *ctx.program_id {
        return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
    }

    let mut index = current_index + 1; // jupiter swap
    
    if let Ok(ix) = load_instruction_at_checked(index, &ixs) {
        if ix.program_id == crate::id() {
            let ix_discriminator: [u8; 8] = ix.data[0..8]
                .try_into()
                .map_err(|_| FlashFillError::SomeMismatch)?;

            if ix_discriminator == self::instruction::Borrow::discriminator() {
                return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
            } else {
                return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
            }
        }
    } else {
        // no more instructions, so we're missing a repay
        return Err(FlashFillError::SomeMismatch.into());
    }

    Ok(())
}

Then I am having this error:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `instruction` in `self`
  --> programs/jupiter_borrow/src/instructions.rs:48:42
   |
48 |             if ix_discriminator == self::instruction::Borrow::discriminator() {
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `instruction` in `self`
   |
help: consider importing one of these items
   |
1  + use core::borrow::Borrow;
   |
1  + use crate::Borrow;
   |
1  + use crate::__cpi_client_accounts_borrow::Borrow;
   |
1  + use crate::accounts::Borrow;
   |
     and 3 other candidates
help: if you import `Borrow`, refer to it directly
   |
48 -             if ix_discriminator == self::instruction::Borrow::discriminator() {
48 +             if ix_discriminator == Borrow::discriminator() {
   |

error: the `#[global_allocator]` in this crate conflicts with global allocator in: spl_token

Can someone help?

There's actually two issues in that error message:

using the correct Borrow. It looks like there's crate::Borrow and crate::accounts::Borrow in the local context, and I think crate::Borrow is the one you want to use, since you've brought in the instructions with use crate::instructions::*
your project using spl-token but is not enabling the no-entrypoint feature, so in your Cargo.toml, you need something like:

spl-token = { version = "whatever-version-you-want", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }


Still getting the same error

rustc error message is quite helpful, you can follow its recommendations.
You add use core::borrow::Borrow; at the top of your file and refer to it directly as it is suggested with if ix_discriminator == Borrow::discriminator() { instead of the line with the error.

Did not help much. Now I am getting different errors. I think with the given code you will be able to check yourself by copy paste and anchor build after that
